# Mantis User Authentication fails to authenticate in Dokuwiki

Tags: mantis, dokuwiki

I have installed Mantisbt 1.2.17 and it seems to be working correctly.

I have installed dokuwiki Release 2014-09-29a "Hrun" on a separate url on the same server and it seems to be working well.

I have followed the instructions for integrating Dokuwiki into mantis as shown [here](http://www.mantisbt.org/wiki/doku.php/mantisbt%3Aissue:7075%3Aintegration_with_dokuwiki):

with this code in /dokuwiki/conf/local.php

```
$conf['title'] = 'Technical Wiki';
$conf['lang'] = 'en';
// $conf['authtype']='mantis';
$conf['license'] = '0';
$conf['useacl'] = 1;
$conf['superuser'] = '@admin';
$conf['disableactions'] = 'register';
```

When I click on the wiki link from the mantis menu, **it takes me to the wiki, but I am not logged in and it will not allow me to create page/edit.** The login link in dokuwiki is active and if I log in using a dokuwiki user, I am able to edit with no problem.

When I was following the integration instructions, it said to put the mantis.class.php file into dokuwiki/inc/auth folder, but there was no such folder after dokuwiki install. I created a folder and put it there and also included it directly in the inc folder

Looking at my error log, I get this type of error:
 client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/dokuwiki/data/security.png,

with this code in /dokuwiki/conf/local.php ('authtype' set to 'mantis")

```
$conf['title'] = 'Technical Wiki';
$conf['lang'] = 'en';
$conf['authtype']='mantis';
$conf['license'] = '0';
$conf['useacl'] = 1;
$conf['superuser'] = '@admin';
$conf['disableactions'] = 'register';
```

I get the dokuwiki logon screen with a message:
**User authentication is temporarily unavailable.** If this situation persists, please inform your Wiki Admin.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: can't help you with mantis, but the error in your error log (security.png) is perfectly fine and completely unrelated to your mantis problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ah actually, I can help you. The mantis page you linked describes the installation of an old style auth backend. Those are no longer supported since the introduction of Auth Plugins in DokuWiki Weatherwax. Someone needs to convert that class into a proper auth plugin.